# Parsing a server log file every x amount of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, parsing

i am trying to parse a server log file in javascript every 24 hours and store the information in a database (mongodb).

the parsing and storage of the data is what is confusing me

the log file is in the following format

```
[2020.02.05-10.44.02:841][244]2020.02.04_10.44.02: USERNAME joined this SERVER!
[2020.02.05-11.45.58:147][188]2020.02.04_11.45.58: GROUPNAME slayed a monster!
[2020.02.05-11.46.39:852][437]2020.02.04_11.46.39: USERNAME left this SERVER!
[2020.02.05-11.46.39:854][437]2020.02.04_11.46.39: GROUPNAME was slayed by GROUPNAME
[2020.02.05-11.46.57:317][956]2020.02.04_11.59.59: USERNAME joined this server!
```

i want to grab the time spent on the server for each user, the amount of kills etc.

i havent really done anything like this before and is proving quite challenging, i think it is the fact that the log file can end with a user online, so i need to compensate for that in the next parsing of the log.

i can split the log into an array per line, map over it and then check whether the value includes 'joined this SERVER', i can grab the data that way but im confused on how to store it and then compare against the next value includes 'left this SERVER'..

Maybe regex would be a better solution? as i say i havent had to do anything like this before so i wouldnt know.

any help or example code would be much appreciated.

Comment: How many users are online on a typical day? Is the log just one massive continuous file, or split by day?

Comment: I cannot say how many users per day. The log is split every 24 hours

Comment: You're gonna have a hard time getting the kills per user unless you have some magic to tell you which group the user is in.

Comment: Does the log file ever have issues such as failing to log `USERNAME left this SERVER!` which causes consecutive `USERNAME joined this SERVER!`?

Comment: Obviously lol it will have to be kills per group & No it doesn't, when the log is fetched it contains 24 hours of data, after 24 hours it is then replaced with new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a program schedule the daily running of your script.

In your script:

1. Instantiate a data structure (just an object will do!), keyed by user ID, to record start and end times, plus kills etc.
2. Hydrate the data structure with the incomplete information from last night (from a file)
3. Open a stream to the log file and, line-by-line, parse it into variables using a regular expression, populating your data structure
4. Each time a "user goes offline" log entry is detected, write the calculated data for that user to the database, and remove the entry for that user from the data structure
5. Once the log has been parsed, any information left in the data structure is the result of the user being online. Write this to disk, ready for the following night

Comment: Ok this makes sense to me now it is written down, i will go at it again working off of this and see how it goes